# Why doesn't cong typecheck in Idris 2

Tags: idris

I'm writing a function to test propositional equality of `Nat`, and it typechecks in Idris 1.

```
sameNat : (n : Nat) -> (m : Nat) -> Maybe (n = m)
sameNat Z Z = Just Refl
sameNat (S n) (S m) = case sameNat n m of
                        Just e => Just (cong e)
                        Nothing => Nothing
sameNat _ _ = Nothing
```

But it doesn't typecheck in Idris 2 (0.4.0) and I got this error.

```
Error: While processing right hand side of sameNat. When
unifying n = m and Nat m e -> :: ?x ?xs n m e.
Mismatch between: n = m and Nat m e -> :: ?x ?xs n m e.
```

It typechecks when I write a specific version of `cong` and use it.

```
cong' : n = m -> S n = S m
cong' Refl = Refl
```

Why doesn't this typecheck and how can I make it typecheck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type signature of `cong` changed:

Idris 1:

```
cong : (a = b) -> f a = f b
```

Idris 2:

```
Prelude.cong : (0 f : (t -> u)) -> a = b -> f a = f b
```

Comment: Oh, so I need to pass `S` explicitly. Thank you.